# how can I check for more than I input for if...else android

Tags: android, if-statement

This is my code. I want to compare within morning,afternoon and evening. can I do like this?

```
private String interpretFT(int morninghour, int afternoonhour, int eveninghour)
    {
        if (morninghour > afternoonhour )
        {
            return "Time to exercise : Morning";
        }
        else if (afternoonhour > eveninghour)
        {
            return "Time to exercise : Afternoon";
        }
        else if (eveninghour > morninghour)
        {
            return "Time to exercise : Evening";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Please have the freetime to have some exercise";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are comparing `int` and that seems alright unless you come up with detailed description of your problem statement

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: it change to one int only. cannot be 3 int in that brackets

Comment: String freetimeInterpretation = interpretFT(freeTimeValue);

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with this?
If you want to get string from current time:

```
  private String interpretFT(int morningHour, int afternoonHour, int eveningHour, int currentHour){

    String result = "";

    if (currentHour => morninghour && currentHour < afternoonhour )
    {
        result = "Time to exercise : Morning";
    }
    if (currentHour => afternoonhour && currentHour < eveninghour)
    {
        result = "Time to exercise : Afternoon";
    }
    if (currentHour => eveninghour && currentHour < morninghour)
    {
        result = "Time to exercise : Evening";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Please have the freetime to have some exercise";
    }

return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To compare I suggest use ternary operator, for example:

```
private String interpretFT(int morninghour, int afternoonhour, int eveninghour) {
        return ((morninghour > afternoonhour) ? "Time to exercise : Morning" :
                (afternoonhour > eveninghour) ? "Time to exercise : Afternoon" :
                        (eveninghour > morninghour) ? "Time to exercise : Evening" :
                                "Please have the freetime to have some exercise");

    }
```